# Persistent session_id inside an iframe

Tags: php, ajax, session, iframe

I have a php system that works fine stand-alone but not when embedded in an iframe.
It's embedded in a page on another domain.. and consists of:
main.php graps a parameter off iframe-URL, look up in MySQL, sets a session variable and draws a grid.
Then, using ajax, tries to get data to display in the grid.
- but the ajax.php doesn't have the same session_id() ?!?
AND in subsequent ajax-calls for data (to update the grid) the session_id() keeps changing!

To recap: ALL my PHP is inside the SAME iframe - no XS trouble..?
There IS a session_start() in all the right places (it works stand-alone).
The session_save_path() is the same in main.php and ajax.php (and they're in the same dir)
I've seen and tried different versions of header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"') - fruitlessly : (

Found it: My browser didn't allow Third Party Cookies - including the session-cookie!
But isn't this wrong - no cookies are being shared across domains (it stays inside the iframe) ?
- still.. it IS another domain than the one the user asked for in the URL... hmm... shit.

Comment: I could pass the session id in the ajax-call and set it with session_id( $damnit ) - but don't understand WHY ?

Comment: Are you by any chance modifying the session cookie parameters? If not, you could try using `session_set_cookie_params()` to specifically set the cookie to the proper domain. Make sure the cookie is **not** set to httpOnly, as that will make them unavailable for AJAX requests. Try setting a regular cookie in your initial request and outputting the contents of the `$_COOKIE` array on subsequent requests.

Comment: Tried outputting session_get_cookie_params() in both pages: return the same "0,/,,," imploded with commas - everything looks OK but the session_id change on every ajax-call (AND if I right-click + reload frame (main.php) also) cookies seem to disappear if set inside an iframe ?!?

Comment: Ahh the 0 means time to live.. Tried to set it to 900 (15 minutes). session_get_cookie_params() returns "900,/,,," as expected. But STILL the session_id() change every time : (

Comment: Found it: Third party cookies (not allowed)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, the problem was the browser blocking (not allowing) Third Party Cookies.
(That is, ignoring cookies not issued from the server behind the main (visible) URL)

There exists a way to circumvent this security-feature: google "P3P"
- but that's not reliable across browsers (Chrome).

My solution is to keep the session_id in javascript, and append it as an extra parameter in all ajax-calls,
enabling me to pick the relevant session in ajax.php: session_id( $_POST['sessID'] ); session_start( );

This solution does make it somewhat easier for a malicious user to dick around with the session_id.
- since it's now available (for modification) using javascript alone (easier than modifying a cookie)...

I would like to hear peoples thoughts about this "increased vulnerability" ?

Comment: I guess that would be the "less worse" solution, with a way to crypt the ID with a private key or semething, maybe a single usage key that is regenerated at each request.