# How to preserve session after ajax call in iframe?

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, session

I'm having an issue with session not passing through an Ajax call. The app works perfectly fine as standalone web application. But once I use it in iframe, I can see that session is not used properly.
Here's an Ajax call from my main file

```
var sessionId = "<?php Print(session_id()); ?>";
$.post('ajaxget.php', { sessionId: sessionId}, 
function(result){
                console.log(result);
            }, "json").fail(function(j) {});
```

In ajax.php I have this

```
$sid = session_id();
$senddata['callerSession'] = $_POST['sessionId'];
$senddata['ajaxSession'] = $sid;
$senddata['session'] = $_SESSION;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($senddata);
    exit();
```

Running this provides a result where "callerSession" and "ajaxSession" are different ids, though they should be the same. And therefore $_SESSION variable is empty in ajax.php.
I've tried these solutions

- https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-25591.html - didn't work
- [Persistent session_id inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22126788/persistent-session-id-inside-an-iframe) - unable to alter codeigniter's session.

Been stuck on this for quite a while now and I'm lost. I think the problem might be with cookie with session id information not passing correctly but that's just my blind guess. Perhaps there's a way how I could set the session having the needed session's id (tried searching for that but found no ways of doing that)? Any help is appreciated

Comment: how did the example from the codeigniter forum not work? Are you using session with a database?

Comment: I think this is the `SameSite` issue.